# How to split a compressed file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compression, 7z, lzma

I have a 44GB 7z compressed file that I compressed with lzma2 and it took around 11 hours (original file is a text file of 285GB).

```
7z a -t7z Files.7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa
```

So, what I want is to do is to split the file without re-compressing it, to be able to upload/download over simultaneous connections

How would I split and join such a file without going through the 7z recompress process again?

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Nothing really, i just compressed original file with lzma2 for see how much time/ how much i can compress it(from 285GB to 44GB). Im asking how i can split and once i know how its splitted, how i can get with all splited files, the original file again.

Comment: The network speed won't increase when transferring multiple smaller files. In fact, it may be slightly slower.

Comment: it is, i just test it, when i upload 5 files of 5gb i get upload speed total of 350mbps and downloading the same( i have thath contracted with my network) if i do all in 1 file i do not get more than 100mbps in downloading/uploading. And they have enough speed cause its google cloud.

Comment: **@Kusalananda** Yes it does: latency has an effect and that is what download managers do.  **Local Host** As you seem to attract downvotes, I've edited your question to become more succinct and to the point.  **;-)**  please approve edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `man split`:

```
split - split a file into pieces
```

so the command becomes:

```
split --bytes=2M Files.7z
```

this will then create multiple files of 2Mbyte in the current directory named `xaa`, `xab`, `xac`, ... if you want more versatility in the name creation see  `man split`.

[To join them back together have a look here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24630/whats-the-best-way-to-join-files-again-after-splitting-them)

Comment: and how do i get the original file from the splitted files?

Comment: @LocalHost . `cat` the files together in the right order, then uncompress the resulting file.

Comment: okay, then best would be to output splitted files be a number like part1 part2 part3 etc. its possible? so when i cat i know what to put first

Comment: Updated answer. @LocalHost

Comment: with the split output these seems to be the way to go "cat xa{a..g}" , thanks for your help @fabby